# Java and regular expression, substring

Tags: java, regex, substring

I'm am tottaly lost when coming to regular expressions.
I get generated strings like:

```
Your number is (123,456,789)
```

How can I filter out `123,456,789`?

Comment: Also: When you say "filter out," do you mean you want to end up with "Your number is ()", or you want to end up with the numbers?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the generated strings can be of different size, otherwise it would be easy to substring it using a start index and a stop index by using the String.substring method, but it is not possible since the strings are of different size. But the format are always <code>Your number is (xxx,xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx)</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str="Your number is (123,456,789)";
str = str.replaceAll(".*\\((.*)\\).*","$1");
```

or you can make the replacement a bit faster by doing:

```
str = str.replaceAll(".*\\(([\\d,]*)\\).*","$1");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex for extracting the number including the commas

```
\(([\d,]*)\)
```

The first captured group will have your match. Code will look like this

```
String subjectString = "Your number is (123,456,789)";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([\\d,]*)\\)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String resultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(resultString);
}
```

Explanation of the regex

```
"\\(" +          // Match the character “(” literally
"(" +           // Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "[\\d,]" +       // Match a single character present in the list below
                      // A single digit 0..9
                      // The character “,”
      "*" +           // Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
"\\)"            // Match the character “)” literally
```

This will get you started http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for a very good answer! I was also looking for a good reference, so thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"\\(([^)]+)\\)"
```

or

```
int start = text.indexOf('(')+1;
int end = text.indexOf(')', start);
String num = text.substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void showHowToUseRegex()
{
    final Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("Your number is \\((\\d+),(\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
    final Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("Your number is (123,456,789)");
    if (m.matches()) {
        Log.d("xxx", "0:" + m.group(0));
        Log.d("xxx", "1:" + m.group(1));
        Log.d("xxx", "2:" + m.group(2));
        Log.d("xxx", "3:" + m.group(3));
    }
}
```

You'll see the first group is the whole string, and the next 3 groups are your numbers.

Comment: That wasn't specified in the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
String str = "Your number is (123,456,789)";
str = new String(str.substring(16,str.length()-1));
```

Comment: What reason for exactly known string to use index search of '('?

Comment: Don't use regex, when you could use something else.